# Is there any good documentation for the openapi-generator library?

Tags: openapi-generator

I’d like to use the openapi-generator Maven plugin to generate our API reference docs. I cannot find thorough documentation for the Openapi Generator. For example, there is no explanation of what the so-called “input Openapi spec file”. Where can I find better documentation? Perhaps there is some manual in the original Codegen site?

Comment: Have you checked the official docs? https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin